# How to change default save location for Atom in Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git, github, atom-editor, configuration-files

I have recently installed Git Bash and set Atom as my default editor  by
$ git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"

When I try to create or edit a .py file in Git Bash, Atom opens up OK, but then I get this error (below) and I cant use -add or commit commands. there's the screenshot.

[image]

$ Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or rel
Function provided here: Object. (C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.55.0\resources\app.asar\node_modules\github\lib\worker.js:79:22)
Remote event names: crashed, destroyed

Below is some of my data.

[image]

I have discovered that my error is caused by Atom saving my new py files in this directory, rather than in my dedicated Git repo..

For example, free_memory.py gets saved in  C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.55.0

[image]

Instead of C:\Users\Maria\Git_course\scripts

[image]

I have  added ';C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\atom\bin' to my Environmental Variable PATH...

How can I save these files in C:\Users\Maria\Git_course\scripts(make it the default save location)?
I am also confused about why Atom has two .exe files? One is within the Atom folder while the other is within the app-1.55 folder within the main Atom folder?

[image]

How can I configure it correctly?
I'm on  Windows 7 64-bit.

thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is related to [`atom/atom` issue 19849](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/19849#issuecomment-559757142)

> This bug always triggers on my Windows installation, and so far I only found one workaround: use `atom --wait --new-window` instead of `atom --wait`.
>
> This will replicate Atom's original behaviour of opening the commit message in a fresh new window instead of adding a tab to an existing window - this way I only have to close that new window (which is as simple as hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> twice) instead of having to close and then reopen a project window.